# How to avoid pagebreaks before/after centered text

Tags: spacing, page-breaking

I have the problem that I need to typeset some text (in this case the string `Solution:`) and on the next line a centered image. I went with something like the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\rule{1cm}{18cm} % Just here to simulate some text/images/...

Solution:
\nopagebreak

\begin{center}
\nopagebreak
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The text `Solution:` is set in my installation on the first page with quite some space below it On the next page the 5cmx5cm block that contains the solution itself is set. I do not like this as it looks awkward.

Additionally, the underlying tex document is typeset twice (using `\input`), once only the exercises and once with the solutions. This makes it hard to manually add `\pagebreak` macros as it will break the exercise-only version.

The only way to get mostly what I want to achieve is to use

```
\begingroup
\vspace{1em}\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\par\vspace{1em}
\endgroup
```

This has some different spacing compared to the classical `center` environment. Of course, I could tune it yet a bit.

So: Is there a better way to get this done in LaTeX than to fall back to the TeX directive `\centering`?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `\nopagebreak` does not override other favorable break-points inserted by other commands, as does the `center` environment. The regular way to prevent such breaks is with `\samepage`, but you still need `\nopagebreak` between paragraphs. So

```
\rule{1cm}{18cm} % Just here to simulate some text/images/...

\begin{samepage}
Solution:

\begin{center}
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{center}

\end{samepage}
```

Note that commands like `\samepage` can be used as an environment to limit their scope. No `\nopagebreak`s were necessary here, but would be if there were any ordinary paragraph breaks included.

A better approach, though, is probably to use the needspace package, an declare `\needspace{6cm}` before the solution. This will make a ragged bottom page when needed.

Comment: The thing is that I do not know the height of the solution a priori as I want to create an environment that manages all the relevant parts. I think I will try with `\samepage` a bit unless there comes a better idea up.

Answer (score 0):

Without packages, use a minipage:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\rule{1cm}{18cm} 

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
Solution:
\begin{center}
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Another simpler solution is use a header, even if you want "Solution" as normal text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\rule{1cm}{18cm} 

\subsubsection*{\normalfont Solution:}

\begin{center}
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The minipage approach will avoid any pagebreaks within it. So if the solution is lengthy, it cannot be broken accordingly, right?

Comment: @ChristianWolf The minipage is unbreakable. For a large solution, you should include in the minipage the header "Solution:" and only one-two paragrapsh to avoid the widow header, al left the resto of the solution as normal text  ... or you can convert "Sotution:" a true header (see the edited answer).